# Numeric-Text-Box with localized decimal point

Tags: angular-kendo

I think I have noticed a bug when initializing numeric text box with certain value when using localized decimal point e.g. ',' (comma) which is in my language (Icelandic).

here is a demo: (notice that selectedValue is initialized with value 1.23 but displays as 123.00)

http://jsbin.com/IYiDUbUx/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed by Mihai Bazon.
https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues/136